# How to have an optional file that gets copied to the output directory in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

On a large (team and code) project, we have set up the various `App.config`s and `Web.config`s to reference an (optional) `local.config` file so that developers can override some things when running locally. `local.config` is listed in `.gitignore` so it's ignored and not included in commits. This works very well to support local configuration overrides.

However, for console apps, `local.config` isn't copied to the output directory by default. I can set its properties in VS so that it's copied to the output - it gets listed in the `.csproj` file like this:

```
<None Include="local.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

This works fine in VS, even when a particular developer does not have a `local.config` file at all. However, it fails in the VSTS build jobs because apparently msbuild doesn't like it when a listed file is absent.

Is there any way to configure the project or msbuild so that it will tolerate/ignore the missing (optional) file instead of failing the builds?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can be done by using an msbuild condition:

```
<None Include="local.config" Condition="Exists('local.config')">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```